# Replace multiple column values if a value is the same in both data frames

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   1   Биир    биир    NUM num NumType=Card    _   _   _   _
1   2   паартаҕа    паарта  NOUN    n   Case=Dat|Number=Sing    _   _   _   _
2   3   киһи    киһи    NOUN    n   Case=Nom|Number=Sing    _   _   _   _
3   4   олорор  олор    VERB    v   Person=3|Tense=Pres _   _   _   _
4   5   .   .   PUNCT   punct   _   _   _   _   _
```

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   1   Биир    _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _
1   2   уол _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _
2   3   турар   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _
3   4   уонна   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _
4   5   ааҕар   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _
5   6   .   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _
```

How do I replace specific columns if a value from the second df is in the first one?

```
df2[1].isin(df1[1])

0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
```

For all `True`, replace columns `2,3,4,5`.
The output should be this:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   1   Биир    биир    NUM num NumType=Card    _   _   _   _
1   2   уол _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _
2   3   турар   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _
3   4   уонна   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _
4   5   ааҕар   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _
5   6   .   .   PUNCT   punct   _   _   _   _   _
```

I tried using where but it gives me an error that the length of 2 dfs is different.

```
df2[[2, 3, 4, 5]].where(df2[1].isin(df1[1]), df1[[2, 3, 4, 5]].values)
```

Is there any other way to replace multiple columns by a specific condition?

Comment: Are you trying to do a merge?

Comment: @user17242583 no, I'm trying to retrieve the same df2, but with column values from df1, if they match

Comment: Your question is confusing, because: 1. the underscores everything are hard to understand, 2. the first dataframe and your expected output are nothing alike. The _second_ dataframe is very similar to the output one, except in the output df, a few rows are taken from the first dataframe, which makes me think you're looking for a merge.

Comment: @user17242583 in this case underscores are just empty values, it's a conllu format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way is to: 1.concat, 2.drop_duplicates, 3.filter, 4.sort, here goes:

```
df = pd.concat([df2, df1]).drop_duplicates('1', keep='last')
df = df[df['1'].isin(df2['1'])].sort_values('0')
```

df:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Биир | биир | NUM | num | NumType=Card | _ | _ | _ | _ |
| 1 | 2 | уол | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ |
| 2 | 3 | турар | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ |
| 3 | 4 | уонна | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ |
| 4 | 5 | ааҕар | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ |
| 4 | 5 | . | . | PUNCT | punct | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ |